# Swiftui: align selected text in picker to leading edge

Tags: swiftui, ios14, swiftui-navigationview, swiftui-form

Currently I've a `picker` included in a `Section` included in a `Form` what I'm trying to reach is to align the selected value of the `picker` to the leading in both iOS 13 and 14, I've tried many solutions such as `labelsHidden()` but with no result, kindly find the code sample that generates the following screenshot on iOS 14, any help would be appreciated [image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedStrength = "Mild"
    let strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("", selection: $selectedStrength) {
                        ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) {
                            Text($0)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems to be a problem only when using `Picker` inside a `Form`...

Comment: @aheze actually I need to go to a separate screen to select some value from the array, that's why the `Form` is necessary in this case

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `Text()` with a `Spacer()` in a `HStack()`

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var selectedStrength = "Mild"
    let strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Section {
                    Picker("", selection: $selectedStrength) {
                        ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) { t in
                            HStack {
                                Text(t)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to use .frame() and .labelsHidden()

```
struct ContentView: View {
@State private var selectedStrength = "Mild"
let strengths = ["Mild", "Medium", "Mature"]

var body: some View {
    NavigationView {
        Form {
            Section {
                Picker("", selection: $selectedStrength) {
                    ForEach(strengths, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                .frame(width: 160, alignment: .leading)
                .labelsHidden()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

tested on IOS 16